# Dokku deploy failing with upgraded Rails 6.0 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, dokku

I have been upgrading a Rails 5.2 application to Rails 6. I have not yet installed Webpack but I am getting the following deploy error on Dokku (which has a similar build system to Heroku):

```
webpack binstubs not found.
Have you run rails webpacker:install ?
Make sure the bin directory or binstubs are not included in .gitignore
Exiting!

!
!     Precompiling assets failed.
!
```

[This is similar error but from a new project and had different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65029528/webpack-binstubs-not-found-on-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dokku (maybe Heroku?) Do not add Webpacker gem until you are ready to migrate to Webpacker.

Rails 6 introduced Webpacker by default into the Gemfile and I copied it in without thinking during the upgrade. I had added the Gem but I had not yet migrated from Sprockets to using Javascript in Webpacks (the default in Rails 6).

During the deploy Dokku saw the Webpacker gem in the gemfile and expected that Webpacker had been installed when it hadn't - resulting in the error.

Removing Webpacker from the Gemfile fixed this until I am ready to look at Webpacker.